Stronger than the strong Bruhat order on $S_n$
Is there a (combinatorially defined) partial order on $S_n$ that is a refinement of the strong Bruhat order but is not yet a linear order?
Of course, I can cook up some refinement by simply taking two incomparable elements and choosing to make one larger than the other (taking care to close this under transitivity), but this is boring, and I guess may lead to a linear order if there aren't that many incomparables. So, instead, I've tried to think of a more combinatorial definition but with no luck (maybe something to do with cycle type?).
This is mostly just out of curiosity. I saw this recent paper by Bouvel, Ferrari, and Tenner titled "Between weak and Bruhat: the middle order on permutations" and was interested if there are more interesting partial orders between strong Bruhat and some linear order.
